# NullPointerException Error for ArrayAdapter and ListView

Tags: listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that receives user input from edit text in a different activity via key "hubahuba". When I click on the tap that contains this .class I receive the NullPointerException Error based on the logcat I know it has to do with my "String trackinput" Line PLEASE any help guys???

```
 public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

LisstView lv;
String trackinput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_argue_list);

           //listViewCode

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            //Intent to receive from other activity

    Intent i = getIntent();

    String trackinput = i.getExtras().getString("hubahuba");

            //basic adapter

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.add(0, trackinput);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

This is from activity 1 going to the listView in Activity 2:

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ArgueListActivity.class); 
 i.putExtra("hubahuba",whatedit.getText().toString()); 
 whatedit.setText("");
}
```

Comment: In `onCreate()` here, you're declaring a local variable called `lv` that hides what I assume is the member variable. Are you initializing the member `lv` at some point?

Comment: @Collin Can you provide an example how initializing the member lv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new instance of `Intent`

You can just do it like this:

```
String trackinput = getIntent().getStringExtra("hubahuba");
```

Also as Collin pointed out

```
LisstView lv;
```

and

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

are ambiguous

---

After you put data into the intent you have to start the activity, and pass it the intent
to it.

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ArgueListActivity.class); 
 i.putExtra("hubahuba",whatedit.getText().toString()); 
 whatedit.setText("");
 startActivity(i)
}
```

Comment: @LimpLimp please show the code that puts the string in the intent

Comment: When I add this method I no longer get the NullPointer but it does not receive the bundle any ideas on how to implement both ( Bundle and String trackinput = getIntent().getStringExtra("hubahuba"); )